# Simplest way to export executor queue size to Prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

I'm migrating existing service metrics to Prometheus, I'm trying to find the cleanest way to export existing executor metrics:

For example if I want to expose:

```
executorService.getQueue().size()
```

I could have a gauge that increments on submitting a new task to the executor and decrements when it finishes. However that changes the current metric behavior (and requires quite a bit of refactoring).

If instead I convert it to a collector, then I run into the fact that Prometheus complains about there are duplicate `#HELP` blocks for the same metric. (This happens because I have multiple executors and am using labels to break them apart).

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: Java, It appears that a solution sharing a `GaugeMetricFamily` may work. I'll post an answer with details if it feels right.